# error returning data foreach find mongodb array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am consulting a document and with the result I consult another `model` but in the end, nothing is returning to me, the `foreach` does not wait for the `await`.

```
ShoppingCart.find({
   "userId": id
}).then(async ShoppingCart => {
   let distinctTypes = ShoppingCart[0].productsCart;
   distinctTypes.sort(function(r, u) {
      return r.manufacturerId > u.manufacturerId ? 1 : r.manufacturerId < u.manufacturerId ? -1 : 0
   });
   let products = [];
   let data2 = await distinctTypes.forEach(async function(thisType) {
      let id = thisType.productId;
      let data = await Product.findById(id).then(Product => {
         thisType.productId = Product;
         products.push(thisType);
         return products;
      });
      return data; ///at this point the information is correct
   });
   return data2;
});
```

> "data": null

Answer (score 0):

This happens because forEach does not executes in a synchronised way.
Use For of loop instead.

**Detailed answer : -** [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop][1])

Comment: Very good answer       for await (const prod of distinctTypes) {}

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `Array.prototype.forEach` does not wait. Instead, you should use `Array.prototype.map` and `Promise.all`

```js
ShoppingCart.find({
   "userId": id
}).then(async cart => {
   let distinctTypes = cart[0].productsCart;
   distinctTypes.sort(function(r, u) {
      return r.manufacturerId > u.manufacturerId ? 1 : r.manufacturerId < u.manufacturerId ? -1 : 0
   });
   const distinctTypesWithProducts = await Promise.all(
     distinctTypes.map(async function(thisType) {
        let id = thisType.productId;
        const product = await Product.findById(id)
        thisType.product = product // changed assignment of product to thisType.product
        return thisType
     });
   );
   return distinctTypesWithProducts;
});
```

You could simplify the above with a [project](https://github.rubico.land) I started. Contributions are welcome.

```js
const { pipe, assign, map, get } = require('rubico')

// userId => cart
const findCartByUserID = userId => ShoppingCart.find({ userId })

// [distinctType] => [distinctType] sorted
const sortDistinctTypes = distinctTypes => distinctTypes.sort((r, u) => {
  return r.manufacturerId > u.manufacturerId ? 1 : r.manufacturerId < u.manufacturerId ? -1 : 0
})

// distinctType => distinctTypeWithProduct
const assignProduct = assign({
  product: pipe([
    get('productId'), // distinctType => productId
    Product.findById, // productId => product
  ]), // distinctType.product = product; return distinctType
})

// userId => [distinctTypeWithProduct, distinctTypeWithProduct, ...]
const getDistinctTypesWithProductFromUserID = pipe([
  findCartByUserID,
  // userId => cart

  get([0, 'productsCart']),
  // cart => distinctTypes

  sortDistinctTypes,
  // distinctTypes => sortedDistinctTypes

  map(assignProduct),
  // sortedDistinctTypes => [distinctTypeWithProduct, distinctTypeWithProduct, ...]
])

getDistinctTypesWithProductFromUserID(id)
```